# Unity Camera Size Web Player

Tags: c#, ios, camera, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I have a question regarding the different sizes of the web player of unity.
   I have a scene where the user will select the level he wants to play and i the camera can move only on up and down , not sideways , and the user can not zoom in or out.

My problem is that because of the different screen sizes the camera size will exit the bounds of the game and the user will see a black part of the scene.

[image]

What i need to do is to clamp the ortographicSize of the camera. On the left of the map and on the right i have 2 objects which are the borders.

How can i clamp the camera size in order for it to not go over the borders ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The camera.orthographicSize is the half size of the vertical volume (you can use the resolution of the horizontal volume to get the needed vertical volume).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking to implement this: `sizeX/size = width/Height`,
 Use this to calculate SizeX.